# Google + login iOS App rejection from appstore using google sdk v3.x

Tags: ios, google-signin, sfsafariviewcontroller

After digging a lot I am here posting my problem. I am using google sign in latest sdk in my app and the app supports iOS 8+. I am using Xcode 7.2 currently. Recently my app got rejected with the very common reason which many users have experienced in the past:

**FROM APPSTORE**
We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience. Specifically, Google log in takes users to Safari to sign in.

Next Steps

**10.6** Please revise your app to enable users to sign in or register an account in the app.

We recommend implementing the Safari View Controller API to display web content within your app. The Safari View Controller allows the display of a URL and inspection of the certificate from an embedded browser in an app so that customers can verify the webpage URL and SSL certificate to confirm they are entering their sign in credentials into a legitimate page.

**END**

I already know this rejection as apple has rejected lot of apps which are taking the Sign In flow out in the Safari browser. Here are some of the links for reference
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900
https://github.com/Torsten2217/google-plus-platform/issues/900

and some more links you can easily find on Internet

On May 2015 Google released a new sdk with native web view. The complete process of integration is listed here http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/. 
It was working fine with iOS 8 and was presenting a controller too.

Now I was using the latest google sdk which I installed via CocoaPods
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start
The above link from google has a **Try Sign-In for iOS** sample which I tried. It is now opening a native `SFSafariViewController` in iOS 9 only but in iOS 8 the login flow is again going outside the app to Safari browser.

In the comments apple reviewer asked to use `SafariViewController` but the availability of the control is from **iOS 9 and above**. Here is the link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller
How can I achieve this with latest google sdk in iOS 8?
The reviewer has neither mentioned the iOS version he/she was testing.

Now can anyone help me in sorting this out. How can I manage in iOS 8, the native present controller for Google Login page.

Comment: @JAL cmon man. It was a 2013 post. Things have changed a lot. Just re read my question and look for the word SFSafariView

Comment: Why don't **you** read the linked question.  `SFSafariViewController` is only available on iOS 9 and above.  For iOS 8 and below, your answer lies in the linked question.

Comment: @JAL Thats the answer from the apple reviewer to implement `SFSafariViewController` . And thats the whole question I posted in how to overcome this problem using LATEST google sdk. We dont use `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` now as per the new sdks. We even dont have GPPSignIn in API reference list of G+ sign In sdk. I also stated the failure of Google sdk launced in may 2015 too.

Comment: I am also currently having the same problem and it's really frustrating. I am using the newest Google Sign In SDK but it doesn't show SFSafariViewController when signing into google even in iOS 9. Did you do something particular to make it open the SFSafariViewController?

Comment: @tyegah123 I managed to solve that in both iOS 9 and 8 and the app is live now. I ll post the answer shortly.

Comment: @tyegah123 I have posted the complete solution. Have a look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally the problem is sorted out with latest Google+ Sign SDK and the app is also approved by Apple. I am posting a solution for both **iOS 9** and **iOS 8**.
Use **CocoaPods** for integration.

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

To start with login you have to do exactly the same steps mentioned in the **Start Integrating** Section [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

Now in the **Add Sign-In** part, I want some custom button in my custom class of `UIViewController` to initiate the login process. In the developer link of Google, they are redirecting in AppDelegate only. So to avoid this I will not be using `GIDSignInDelegate` in my `AppDelegate` class

I will only be making changes in the following two methods of `AppDelegate`

```
//This is available for iOS 9 and above. So we have to use this method if we are integrating Google Sign In in iOS 9
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject])

//This is available prior iOS 9 and is available for iOS 8,7 etc. This is a deprecated method for iOS 9. You have to override this too if your app supports iOS 8 platform.
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
```

So the definitions will be as follows:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] as? String)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
}
```

Now moving on to our Custom `UIViewController` class i.e `LoginViewController`, implement the `GIDSignInDelegate` and `GIDSignInUIDelegate`

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

}
```

There is a custom UIButton for Google + login whose definition is

```
@IBAction func googleLoginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)

    //assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    if configureError != nil {
     //Handle your error
    }else {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientId
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        //This did the trick for iOS 8 and the controller is presented now in iOS 8
        //We have to make allowsSignInWithBrowser false also. If we dont write this line and only write the 2nd line, then iOS 8 will not present a webview and again will take your flow outside the app in safari. So we have to write both the lines, Line 1 and Line 2
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = false  //Line 1
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = true   //Line 2

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

}
```

Now the implementation of **delegate** methods for Google + Sign In

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in       
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {

        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
      //Perform if user gets disconnected
}
```

Now this will work in both iOS 8 and 9 without moving your app outside to Safari for Login purpose in Google +.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying it out now. But I'm curious, do you have some sort of sharing feature from Google or anything like that inside your app?

Comment: for that you can't use Google login.you have to use Google share sdk

Comment: Nah, I'm not using that sharing feature either. It's just because even when I use Google Sign In SDK, Apple was saying it was Google+ SDK and it was one of the reasons for the app's rejection. So I was wondering if you were using somekinda sharing on your app. But anyway, thank you very very much for your help. I finally got it working on my app. :D

Comment: @tyegah123 The google + sdk for apple is the same as login one. great. If it helps you, kindly upvote the answer.