# Why Google login does not work on a device?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, oauth-2.0

When I use this code in the simulator - it works perfectly:

```
// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let accessToken = user.serverAuthCode // Safe to send to the server

        print("AAA \(accessToken)")
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

but it does not work in a real device. When I tap "Allow" button, it refreshes the page and forwards me to google.com website.

What is a problem?

Comment: have u define its delegates?

Comment: @P.G.Progs the problem is not in delegates. It works on the simulator, but opens google.com when I'm trying to log in from a real device

Comment: Have you check `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in .plist file.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari it does not run this line `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                     sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                     annotation: annotation)`. Need I add something into LSApplication?

Comment: @Doe
I have written a complete answer along with question on how to successfully integrate Google +
Have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630276/google-login-ios-app-rejection-from-appstore-using-google-sdk-v3-x