# unresolved identifier GGLContext without cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-signin

I have followed all of the instructions from Google's Get the `Google Sign-in SDK` for `iOS` (without `CocoaPods`), and I tried simulating the application and I'm getting this error: Use of unresolved identifier `GGLContext`
any help please?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    return true
}
```

Comment: You have to use cocoapods for That GGLContext

Comment: Have you imported `GGLContext ` ?

Comment: @Jecky i don't want to use Cocoa pods any other solution?

Comment: So, What do you want ? If you dont use cocoapods then same error you will get everytime

Comment: i cannot find any import for GGLContext.

Comment: I build one demo for google signin but its size is too much with sdk. Without GGLcontext using GIDSIgnIn

Comment: Search for GIDSignIn, Its better option for it

Comment: i 'm referring [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630276/google-login-ios-app-rejection-from-appstore-using-google-sdk-v3-x) for google sign in . also ' //  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = false  //Line 1
           // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = true   //Line 2' cannot resolved,it says GIDSignin doesn't have these methods.